# Magento + get only configured products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to know how can I show only configured products on listing page?
With this I want to show "number of product(configured)"  in particular category that is on URL.
Please help me in this, it will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter collection of product in list page by using

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type','configurable');
```